# Stop endless loop .sh script

Tags: shell-script, python, kill

I have a script like the one below, hosted on an SSH server:

```
while true
do
python3 main.py
sleep 1
done
```

I have run it with:

```
nohup ./launcher.sh
```

I can kill the python processes using top but of course this doesn't help as they are respawned.

Is there any way to stop the execution of this script?

Comment: Kill the shell that runs the script.

Comment: Can you please advise on how to?
I'm less than knowledgeable on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to identify the pid of the parent process , and kill it

this command will help you to identify the parent process of your python

```
ps fax -o ppid,pid,args
```

or

```
ps fax
```

or

```
pstree -p
```

**f** is a useful flag to display relation between process when using ps

Comment: This worked for me.
I was able to find the parent process because I started my script inside screen, so I terminated that instance of screen.
I suspect that it would be the same without it, but I'm not accepting this just yet, in case a different response comes.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PnerFlner Was the parent process really `screen`? It should have been a shell, like `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: Yes. That was the description next to what ps fax printed.

Comment: @PnerFlner Of the _Python_ process?

Comment: It seemed as if it was the parent process from which all the python processes stemmed from on the depicted tree.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have reviewed the case again. It seems that screen is structured in such a way that /bin/bash is a subprocess of it. So I guess I could have killed bash directly instead of killing screen.

Comment: @PnerFlner That's what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

This should kill the background process:

```
kill $(pgrep -f launcher.sh)
```

Comment: Or just `pkill -f launcher.sh`.

Comment: ^^^ exactly, why using `pgrep` for this?